# Vue count item iterated by v-for with function

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a loop component runned by a function to filter by inputs and selects. Can I get a reactive number of elements renderized by this filter?

```
<component-list class=""v-for="(item, index) in itemsFilters()" :key="index" :propId="item.id"
></component-list>
```

itemsFilter() returns a filter of an object array by selects and inputs. I have a pen with an example of this situation: https://codepen.io/joaosaro/pen/baXgjG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If itemsFilter is either computed or a method:

```
 computed: {
      itemsCount () {
          // itemsFilters is computed 
          return this.itemsFilters.length
          // or a method
          return this.itemsFilters().length
      }
  }
```

Comment: Is what I need, thanks. I need to assign to a data element, so I did that inside itemsCount() and return the data variable. Then I can use on component tag as @change="itemsCount"